# Passing vertex position from vertex to fragment shader - only works when debugging with Nsight

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, nsight

I am trying to pass the vertex positions as a simple `out vec3 pos` from the vertex shader to the fragment shader in order to color vertices based on their position. Here is my vertex shader code:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 position;
out vec3 pos;

uniform mat4 u_model;


void main(){
    pos = position;
    gl_Position = u_model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;
in vec4 pos;

void main(){

    color = vec4(pos.x, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Now this only works when I run the program with the Nsight Graphics Debugger in Visual Studio 2019.

When I execute normally (x64, Debug) it seems to fall back to a default shader, which renders everything white. The vertex and fragment shader posted above stop working.

Comment: You should always check for errors when you compile and link shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the vertex shader output has to match exactly the type of the corresponding input in the next shader stage (fragment shader in this case).
See [interface matching rules between shader stages.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Interface_matching)

In your case the type of the vertex shader output is `vec3`:

```c
out vec3 pos;
```

but the type of the fragment shader input is `vec4`:

```c
in vec4 pos;
```

Change the type of the fragment shader input to `vec3`, to solve the issue.

---

I don't know why this code works with Nsight Graphics Debugger in Visual Studio 2019. The bug is that it should not do so.